# How to calculate price change criteria over a rolling timeframe for market data stored in a PostgreSQL database

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate

I have a postgreSQL 10 database with a table named Period that stores historical price data of several cryptocurrencies. I'm trying to query this data to find where the price has increased by a certain percent over a rolling timeframe i.e. 5% within one day. The relevant table columns are "product_id", "end_time" in seconds since the unix epoch, and "close" the closing price of the period.

**Update for clarification:**

- I want to query every period in the database sorted chronologically by end_time
- I want the results to have additional calculated columns (I called them `buy_signal` and `sell_signal` in my example but they correspond to the `min_period`/`max_period` below) based on the following logic

  1. Find the period with the max close price as `max_period` that occurs within one day of the current period (1440 minutes, table has a row for each minute)
  2. Find the period with the min close price as `min_period` that occurs within one day of the current period **AND where `min_period.end_time < max_period.end_time`**
  3. If the difference between the closing price of `min_period` and `max_period` is > 5%, then the `buy_signal` column corresponding to the row containing the `min_period` is true and the `sell_signal` column of the `max_period` row is true

Most of this is pretty straightforward but I'm stuck on the bolded part in #2. It seems like I need to actually get a reference/alias to the `max_period` in order to add that criteria to the `min_period` query.

Given the following simplified data:

```
id     product_id     start_time     end_time     close
0       BTC-USD         100000        100060       100
1       BTC-USD         100060        100120        99
2       BTC-USD         100120        100180       101
3       BTC-USD         100180        100240       105
4       BTC-USD         100240        100300       104
5       BTC-USD         100300        100360       102
6       BTC-USD         100360        100420       100
7       BTC-USD         100420        100480        98
```

I'd like to be able to query these periods with additional calculated columns to indicate when a local minimum/maximum has occurred and when the difference between the min and max is greater than the threshold. For example:

```
id     product_id     start_time     end_time     close     buy_signal     sell_signal
0       BTC-USD         100000        100060       100
1       BTC-USD         100060        100120        99         true
2       BTC-USD         100120        100180       101
3       BTC-USD         100180        100240       105                         true
4       BTC-USD         100240        100300       104
5       BTC-USD         100300        100360       102
6       BTC-USD         100360        100420       100
7       BTC-USD         100420        100480        98
```

Notice row with id 7 is a local min but it doesn't come before the local max.

The complexity of this query is far beyond my SQL experience and I've spent weeks looking through stack overflow answers and SQL features in my spare time but this ugly query is as far as I've been able to get:

```
SELECT
    end_time,
    close,
    MAX(close) OVER (ORDER BY end_time ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1439 FOLLOWING) AS max_close,
    MIN(close) OVER (ORDER BY end_time ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1439 FOLLOWING) AS min_close,
    ((MAX(close) OVER (ORDER BY end_time ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1439 FOLLOWING) - 
      MIN(close) OVER (ORDER BY end_time ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1439 FOLLOWING)) / 
      MIN(close) OVER (ORDER BY end_time ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1439 FOLLOWING)) AS change_percent,
    CASE WHEN
        ((MAX(close) OVER (ORDER BY end_time ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1439 FOLLOWING) - 
          MIN(close) OVER (ORDER BY end_time ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1439 FOLLOWING)) / 
          MIN(close) OVER (ORDER BY end_time ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 1439 FOLLOWING)) > 0.05
        THEN true
    END AS buy_signal
FROM Period
WHERE product_id='BTC-USD'
```

The obvious problem is this doesn't differentiate between the order of the min and max; it selects the lowest value in the window without regards to whether the min came chronologically before the high based on end_time. I've been struggling with how to combine that time filter with the windowing to find the lowest price that came before the highest price and piece everything together. Another (acceptable) limitation is this only works for one product_id at a time but ideally I'd like the query results to include multiple different product_ids ordered by end_time with the signals being product_id-specific.

My goal is to feed the paginated query results into a java application (I'm using Hibernate) that trains a model using the buy and sell signals. I could use the java application to pre-process the data but with millions of rows it would take hours just to execute and add more complexity than the query option. Apologies for the long question but I didn't want to leave anything out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't really tell what your question is.  How do identify a "date" in the data?  What does "buy_signal" and "sell_signal" have to do with the question?  Do you want local optima or a difference of 5%?

Comment: I want to find local optima but only mark those in the result set when the difference between the optima is above 5%. The buy_signal is simply marking the local minimum and sell_signal marks the local maximum. For example, if the close price went from 100 -> 101 -> 99 I wouldn't want to mark any of those with buy or sell signal equals true because the change is not greater than 5%. You could replace the end_time with a date-time if that simplifies the problem. I simply stored the epoch time that the api returns. Each row spans one minute, so I need more granularity than just a date.

Comment: A different way to state the problem would be how can I find the periods with max and min close values over a window but where the end_time field on the min period is less than the end_time of the max period. I haven't been able to figure out how to query those periods using aliases and then use the min and max periods to add the condition min.end_time < max.end_time.